# Examples of Bianchi Modular forms

Tags: modular-forms, automorphic-forms

Recently, I started learning about Bianchi modular forms. The definition of Bianchi modular forms can be found [here](http://www.lmfdb.org/knowledge/show/mf.bianchi.bianchimodularforms). I have seen very few examples of Bianchi modular forms. So, I would like to ask the following questions:

- Can one give few examples of Bianchi modular forms or give a reference where I can find a few examples?
- In particular, can one construct Eisenstein series in the case of Bianchi modular forms (of arbitrary level and weight)? The following paper of  Jurgen Elstrodt and Fritz Gruenwald  [Eisenstein series on three dimensional hyperbolic space and imaginary quadratic number fields](http://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/pdfcache/PPN243919689_0360/PPN243919689_0360___LOG_0011.pdf) constructs an Eisenstein series of weight $h_{K}$. ($h_{K}$ denotes the class number of $K$)

Please correct me if I'm  wrong (or) imprecise.

Comment: For some examples, try Sengun's papers: https://sites.google.com/site/mhaluksengun/research

Comment: The sense of "weight" for the $h_K$ different Eisenstein series cannot refer to the (right) $K$-type... Rather, from a classical viewpoint, the number of cusps "at level one" (with some technicalities about units) is the class number. This is also true for Hilbert modular forms, and so on.

Comment: For examples of modular forms, see the LMFDB - https://www.lmfdb.org/ModularForm/GL2/ImaginaryQuadratic/